# php input class error handling?

Tags: php, html, class, input, error-handling

I have a login div with two input fields. Every input field will be checked for errors.

When I submit the data there are some problems. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="small">
    <?php if (!isset($errors['a'])):?>
          <input type="text" id="a" name="a" value="<?php echo isset ($_POST['a'])? $_POST['a'] : 'Login'; ?>"/>
     <?php endif;?>

     <?php if (isset($errors['a'])):?>
          <input class="log-error" type="text" id="a" name="a" value="<?php echo isset ($_POST['a'])? $_POST['a'] : 'Login'; ?>"/>
      <?php endif;?>
</div>

<?php if (isset($errors['a'])):?>
     <?php echo "<div id='errordiv'></div><div class='error'>";
      echo $errors['a'][0];
      echo "</div>";
endif;?>

<div class="small">
      <?php if (!isset($errors['b'])):?>
           <input type="text" id="b" name="b" value="<?php echo isset ($_POST['b'])? $_POST['b'] : 'Password'; ?>"/>
      <?php endif;?>

      <?php if (isset($errors['b'])):?>
           <input class="log-error" type="text" id="b" name="b" value="<?php echo isset ($_POST['b'])? $_POST['b'] : 'Password'; ?>"/>
       <?php endif;?>
</div>

<?php if ( ( isset($errors['b']) ) && (empty($errors['a'][0]) == true) ):?>
     <?php echo "<div id='errordiv'></div><div class='error'>";
     echo $errors['b'][0];
     echo "</div>";
endif;?>
```

When submitting the data, it won't display both errors at the same time for the input class. It seems like the value-tag is causing this problem.

When I remove the value-tag from both input fields, it will display the error input class at the same time for both.

Comment: Oh, I agree, code indentation is over-rated.

Comment: You double-closed input tags `/>/>`

Comment: Isn't `&& (empty($errors['a'][0]) == true)` in the conditional on displaying the "b" error message your problem? I mean that seems to indicate that you are not interested in displaying the "b" error message if there is an "a" error right?

Comment: @ghbarratt sorry, just answered that... Didn't see your comment ;(

Comment: @thecatontheflat - Actually your answer came before my comment - but just after I was able to read it. If we are right then your answer is all the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like there is logic misunderstanding.

If you want to display both errors at the time - replace this line

```
<?php if ( ( isset($errors['b']) ) && (empty($errors['a'][0]) == true) ):?>
```

with this

```
 <?php if (isset($errors['b'])):?>
```

Comment: hello, i`m sorry, this is not the problem. as you see i mentioned that the problem belongs to input class error(!) and not the extra error div. this line is working as is it should do. i have two error instances for the user. the first one will be a small error image in the input field- what is the topic of my problem. the second instance will be a user information in a div layer that an user forces to correct the first input and afterwards the second. so the problem is just the input class error. thanks.